# Win-ListView and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, winjs

I'm trying the new [AngularJS and WinJS](https://github.com/winjs/angular-winjs) library.

My HTML looks like this:

```
...
<p>
  <win-list-view item-data-source="manufacturers">
    <win-item-template>
      <div>
        <h4>{{item.data.name}}</h4>
        <h6>{{item.data.location}}</h6>
      </div>

    </win-item-template>
    <win-list-layout></win-list-layout>
  </win-list-view>
</p>
...
```

The 'manufacturers' can be displayed by using {{manufacturers}}, so it's definitely not empty.

I have an error message in my console:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'winListView', required by directive 'winListLayout', can't be found!
```

Now I don't know what I've done wrong. Other elements of WinJS are working like expected, just the WinListView throws an error and does not get displayed in the browser (tested with firefox and chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, shame on me. I was confused by the error message it throwed, but it was just a stupid implementation failure.

Removig the `<p></p>` Tag resolved the problem and the list works like expected.

I just needed three hours to figure that out... :/